# How do i deploy a blohg app to Dotcloud?

Tags: deployment, dotcloud

I made a dynamic website with blohg (http://blohg.org), a Mercurial/Flask/reST-based blogging engine, and it works on my machine. 
I tried to deploy the website/app to Dotcloud following http://docs.blohg.org/deploy/ and http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/python/, ensuring that my dotcloud.yml and wsgi.py files were in the right place.
But when i viewed my app on my Dotcloud URL i got

```
 Internal Server Error
 The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

My wsgi.py file is this:

```
from blohg import create_app
application = create_app('<my_app_name>')
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Is there some way i can turn on debug mode to find out? Have any of you successfully deployed at blohg app to Dotcloud? Any tips?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any utf-8 encoded content in your repository?

If yes, add this to the top of the wsgi file:

```
import os
os.environ['HGENCODING'] = 'utf-8'
```

this is a know bug in the wsgi script template, that will be fixed for
the next release.

If not, I'll need to take a deep look on dotcloud deployment process.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. I don't think i have utf-8 content, but i tried your suggestion anyway. I still get the Internal Server Error.

Comment: My app is called 'home' and here is the output of `dotcloud logs home.www`: `2012/04/18 23:10:04 [error] 70#0: *39 open() "/home/dotcloud/current/static/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.79.37.178, server: home-default-www-0, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "home-tortoisesaid.dotcloud.com"
2012/04/18 23:10:04 [error] 70#0: *39 open() "/home/dotcloud/current/static/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.79.37.178, server: home-default-www-0, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "home-tortoisesaid.dotcloud.com"`

Comment: And when i run `dotcloud ssh home.www` and `less /var/log/supervisor/uwsgi.log` i see: `Wed Apr 18 23:09:45 2012 - added /home/dotcloud/current/ to pythonpath.
Wed Apr 18 23:09:55 2012 - WSGI application 1 (SCRIPT_NAME=) ready on interpreter 0x69e820 pid: 163 (default app)
Wed Apr 18 23:09:55 2012 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request / (ip 10.79.37.178) !!!`

Comment: Just an FYI, not sure if it matters or not, but dotCloud uses uwsgi for the wsgi server. not sure if that has any effect.